# Google Cloud Run + Django + RabbitMQ (or another message broker)

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, messagebroker

I have a contenerized `Django` application, which I deployed on `Google Cloud Run`. For the most time no requests are made to the app, so `GCP` can reduce it to 0 instances (and the billing is small). Some requests provide time consuming tasks and I need to handover them to another service by `RabbitMQ` (or possibly another message broker). I wanted to use pika at the `Django` app side, but if I understand correctly it forces it to be running all the time.

So is there a solution, where I can pass messages to message broker from `Django` app and also listen to message queue, but the app can reduce to 0 instances when the queue is empty (and increase instances if it's not)?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A good consideration would be to use Google Cloud Tasks and Google Cloud Scheduler.

I found [this](https://devblog.kogan.com/blog/django-on-cloudrun) tutorial useful